# java.net.BindException: Address already in use WSO2 APIM

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am following this document and continuously throw java.net.BindException error.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Identity+Server+5.2.0+as+a+Key+Manager+with+API+Manager+2.0.0

This is the log.

```
[2016-11-04 11:44:36,213] ERROR - ThriftAuthenticationServiceComponent Error in starting Thrift Authentication Service 
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not bind to port 10711
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createServer(TSSLTransportFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.getServerSocket(TSSLTransportFactory.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication.TCPThriftAuthenticationService.start(TCPThriftAuthenticationService.java:90)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication.internal.ThriftAuthenticationServiceComponent.startThriftTcpAuthenticatorService(ThriftAuthenticationServiceComponent.java:265)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication.internal.ThriftAuthenticationServiceComponent.startThriftServices(ThriftAuthenticationServiceComponent.java:174)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.thrift.authentication.internal.ThriftAuthenticationServiceComponent.activate(ThriftAuthenticationServiceComponent.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:514)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:290)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLServerSocket.<init>(SSLServerSocket.java:181)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.<init>(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:134)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.createServerSocket(SSLServerSocketFactoryImpl.java:91)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSSLTransportFactory.createServer(TSSLTransportFactory.java:109)
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: This means there is some other process which is running on port 10711 You must kill that other process so that your application can take that port.

Comment: Ok dark, I will try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @dark has mentioned, this happens as another process also running on the same port. If you don't run that other process intentionally, you can kill it.

If you want to run 2 wso2 servers in the same machine, you can [port offset](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Changing+the+Default+Ports+with+Offset) in one of them.

On a related note: There is a Pre-Packaged Identity Server 5.2.0 with API Manager 2.0.0 features installed. So you don't have to install features yourself. See [this doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Configuring+the+Pre-Packaged+Identity+Server+5.2.0+with+API+Manager+2.0.0) for more information.